# How to let docker container install latest dependencies version

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pypi

I have a docker image that is build from Dockerfile. It has pip installation inside with custom library. Now the image is used in `docker-compose` service.

*requirements.txt*

```
example-library-1
example-library-2
```

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

`docker build -t example_user/example_image .`

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    image: example_user/example_image
    ports:
      - "8000:5000"
```

When I have a new version for `example-library-1`, how do I update the docker-compose service to use the new library?

I had tried `docker-compose up -d` and `docker-compose restart web` but it does not check for new library version.

Is there a way to do this without `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up -d`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_build/) key to the compose file.

```yaml
services:
  web:
    image: example_user/example_image
    build:
      context: path/to/context
      dockerfile: path/to/Dockerfile
```

Then you run compose with the `build flag`.

```sh
docker compose up --build
```

That said, compose does not have something like rolling updates. You need to stop to compose service and do up with the build flag in order to rebuild.

If you need to rolling updates, you need to use a different operator, like swarm or Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

The docker-compose build flag is a good idea.

After that I recommend to use --no-cache flag because the docker buildkit may cache some layer.

Check [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/build/) the documentation.

Don't forget to check the DOCKER_BUILDKIT environment variable too.

Comment: build flag and no cache dont do anything if you dont even have a build key in your compose.